# Alert box stuck in endless loop

Tags: javascript, php, alert, page-refresh, window.location

I have an `alert` box which is supposed to refresh the page when the user clicks OK. Instead of this happening, the alert box disappears and then reappears when the user clicks OK.

It's stuck in an endless loop of re-appearing!

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  echo'
  <script>
  alert(\'Reply successfully flagged!\');
  window.location.reload();  
  </script>
  ';
}
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

*Note: I need the `alert` to be in the `if` statement - I can't just use pure Javascript (such as `onclick`)!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, when you make a reload, it will trigger the `POST` parameters to be sent, i.e., the `$_POST['submit']` **will be set**. It is better to set a `SESSION` flag instead.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  echo'
  <script>
  alert(\'Reply successfully flagged!\');
  location.href = location.href;  
  </script>
  ';
}
?>
```

Comment: good solution. disclaimer: [not all browsers](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23735) will repost data with `reload()`, but OP is obviously not using one of those browsers :)

Comment: Unfortunately *(not sure why)* the alert box is still stuck in a loop of appearing.

Comment: @TheCodesee Looks like a caching issue buddy?

Comment: break cache with `window.location.reload(true);`

Comment: @TheCodesee ^ try that?

Comment: No luck still.. :(

Comment: @TheCodesee Try `location.href = location.href;`

Comment: @PraveenKumar That did it.. we got there in the end! Cheers :)

Comment: @TheCodesee That does a `GET` request instead.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I was actually able to use my original code (without the sessions) and just change the line of code to `location.href = location.href;`

Answer (score 2):

change

```
window.location.reload();
```

with

```
location.href = window.location.href;
```

Comment: note that the post data will be lost with this approach, but that's probably OK in this context because it's just shooting a confirmation message and reloading, so the data probably isn't needed anymore. moreover, it's probably better so as to not insert duplicate db records on post.